# itunesConnect (user control over 1 app only)

Tags: app-store-connect

I want to create a paid app for a client. She wants me to build her a certain app and upload it via my account to app store.

She wants to split revenues, but at the same time to be able to check the number of downloads and the financial reports concerning her app.

At itunesConnect, a user can be given "financial ROLE" where he/she can view Sales&Trends for all apps.

IS THERE A WAY TO VIEW SALES & TRENDS for only 1 app instead???

Comment: No, your client should really have her own account. Especially since the app is going under your name, not hers, and your account is supposed to be only for you and your business. So while you can set roles, you can't limit what these roles can do to specific apps.

Comment: Yes, you can, behaviour has changed, [check this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/43857643/1634890)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Set up an account with https://www.appfigures.com you can then link it with your itunes connect account and set up a sub account for othjer users limiting it to data from certain apps. Reports can be set up to email out to clients for specific apps too and the statistics, reporting and layout are better than iTunes connect in my opinion.

Answer (score 0):

**Yes.**

When adding or editing roles in iTunes Connect (users and roles), you can limit which app or apps the user will be able to see.